# Protecting Vector Tile Server Data

Tags: vector-tiles, security, amazon-web-services, tile-server, pbf

I am deploying a Vector Tile Server on AWS with data I don't want to make publicly available and there are two main elements I want to cover regarding the security of the data

1. The tile server needs to be private. To accomplish this I need to set up an authentication method. I have this covered by using Cognito and serving the tile server with a Cloudfront distribution.
2. (And here is what I don't know how to fix) The tile server sends .pbf files (they can be downloaded from the network tab on the browser), even when I have users authenticating I would like to protect the data from them. Basically I don't want my authenticated users downloading the tiles from the pbf files

Is there any way to only show the data on the browser without sending the tiles in .pbf?

Another option is to encrypt/decrypt this tiles but how to accomplish this? Is there any docs or place with a **how to** on this?

Comment: switch to using png or jpeg tiles if you want to protect your vectors - otherwise the client will always have your data

Comment: To be able to display something you need to download something ; it make no sense to distribute vector tile and at the same time trying to forbid access to the tile. As said by @IanTurton the way to protect data is to serve image (user will download the image but they won't get anything more than a screen capture would give them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I don't want my authenticated users downloading the tiles from the pbf files

If you're sending data to the browser (which you are), there is nothing you can do to prevent users accessing that data. They already have it.

> Another option is to encrypt/decrypt this tiles but how to accomplish this? Is there any docs or place with a how to on this?

This doesn't help you. If you're accessing the tiles over HTTPS, they're already encrypted - and the browser is decrypting them for the user. Again, if the browser has the data, the user has the data.